# How to adjust the width of a div with position:fixed to parent?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to adjust the width of a div with position:fixed to parent in Bootstrap?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="sidebar">
        SIDEBAR
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
      x<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I have to rigidly determine the width of the parent or can it be done automatically? If yes, how? Maybe bootstrap have something for that?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/webayvsg/

Comment: i think what you need is position: sticky

Comment: @ChrisLi yes, please add new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If browser support is not a big issue you can use position: sticky

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```